# Display only IP addresses from nslookup without writing output to file

Tags: linux, shell-script, awk, scripting

i am a student newly studying cybersecurity. We are using kali linux for the phases of pen-testing. 
I'm new to bash script too.

Command:

```
nslookup -type=mx cathay.com.sg
```

EXAMPLE OUTPUT

```
Server:     192.168.48.2
Address:    192.168.48.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
cathay.com.sg   mail exchanger = 0 cathay-com-sg.mail.protection.outlook.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

I would like for it to only display:

```
192.168.48.2
192.168.48.2#53
```

However, my current script

```
#!/bin/bash
#nslookup but display only IP
nslookup -type=mx cathay.com.sg
|awk -F":" '{print $2}'
```

Results in this error:

```
./nslookupscr.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
./nslookupscr.sh: line 4: `|awk -F":" '{print $2}''
```

I have heard of using dig instead but we have not yet covered that. We only learned about awk and grep for formatting so i am not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: What's goal of this? `nslookup blah` will answer same two first lines, as this lines represent YOUR dns configuration.

Comment: The error comes from the fact that the `awk` command or at least the preceding `|` symbol should be on the line above. Starting a new command with `|` does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

## IP Address returned by `nslookup`

Reading your request, you seem to try to display ***MX*** IP Adress for a domain.

But, `nslookup` first lines report only name and ip address of **your** configured DNS:

```
nslookup -type=mx cathay.com.sg | cat -n
     1      Server:         192.168.1.1
     2      Address:        192.168.1.1#53
     3
     4      Non-authoritative answer:
     5      cathay.com.sg   mail exchanger = 0 cathay-com-sg.mail.protection.outlook.com.
     6
     7      Authoritative answers can be found from:
     8      cathay.com.sg   nameserver = ns2.dreamhost.com.
     9      cathay.com.sg   nameserver = ns3.dreamhost.com.
    10      cathay.com.sg   nameserver = ns1.dreamhost.com.
    11      ns1.dreamhost.com       internet address = 64.90.62.230
    12      ns2.dreamhost.com       internet address = 208.97.182.10
    13      ns3.dreamhost.com       internet address = 66.33.205.230
```

Real answer begin after line 4 and contain only one line, telling MX (with priority = 0) has name: `cathay-com-sg.mail.protection.outlook.com`.

From there, you have to ask (at least) one second question:

```
nslookup cathay-com-sg.mail.protection.outlook.com |cat -n
     1      Server:         192.168.1.1
     2      Address:        192.168.1.1#53
     3
     4      Non-authoritative answer:
     5      Name:   cathay-com-sg.mail.protection.outlook.com
     6      Address: 104.47.124.36
     7      Name:   cathay-com-sg.mail.protection.outlook.com
     8      Address: 104.47.126.36
```

Again, answer begin after line 4, and contain two `Address:`.

### Usig `dig`, under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could do simply:

```
mapfile -t mxnames < <(dig +noall +answer mx cathay.com.sg)
mxnames=("${mxnames[@]##*[ $'\t']}")
mapfile -t mxips < <(dig +noall +answer ${mxnames[@]})
mxips=("${mxips[@]##*[ $'\t']}")
```

Then

```
declare -p mxips mxnames
```

could return something like:

```
declare -a mxips=([0]="67.205.10.249" [1]="77.32.207.225" [2]="104.47.125.36" [3]="104.47.126.36")
declare -a mxnames=([0]="cathay.com.sg." [1]="cathay-com-sg.mail.protection.outlook.com.")
```

You could use

```
for ip in ${mxips[@]};do
    ping -{c,W}1 $ip &>/dev/null && echo $ip ok || echo $ip -- &
        sleep .02
  done |
    cat
77.32.207.225 ok
67.205.10.249 ok
104.47.125.36 --
104.47.126.36 --
```

#### Some explanations:

- Syntaxe `dig +noall +answer <QUERY>` will return only one line by answer, like:

  ```
   dig +noall +answer mx cathay.com.sg
   cathay.com.sg.    12345   IN   MX   0 cathay-com-sg.mail.protection.outlook.com.

   dig +noall +answer $mxname
   cathay-com-sg.mail.protection.outlook.com. 10 IN A 104.47.125.36
   cathay-com-sg.mail.protection.outlook.com. 10 IN A 104.47.126.36
  ```

Please have a look at `man dig` for more informations.

- Syntax `${var##* }` are so called *Parameter expansion*, will drop string from left until last **space**.

  ```
   mxname=${mxname##* }
  ```

  Will drop left part of `dig`'s answer, then store `cathay-com-sg.mail.protection.outlook.com.` into `$mxname`, like

  ```
   mxips+=(${line##* })
  ```

  will add last part of previous answer into `$mxips` **array**.

Please have a look at `man bash`, search for ***Parameter Expansion***: 
`man -P'less +"/^ *Parameter Expansion"' bash`.

### Or using `nslookup`, but with only 1 run for 2 queries:

As `nslookup` could run in *interactive* mode, and so may answer multiple queries, there is a function using 1 ***fork*** to `nslookup` for asking as many queries needed for listing all ip address for one domain:

```
mxIps ()  { 
    local target=$1 line foo;
    local -a mxnames=() mxips=();
    mkfifo fifo-nsl;                 # Fifo for binding nslookup output
    exec 7> >(stdbuf -i0 -o0 nslookup >fifo-nsl);
    exec 6< fifo-nsl;
    rm fifo-nsl;                     # As FD 6 and 7 are open, we could remove them
    printf "set type=mx\n%s\n" $target 1>&7;  # 1st query
    read -u 6 line;                           # wait for answer and drop 1st line
    while read -t .002 -u 6 line; do
        [ "$line" ] && [ -z "${line%%$target*mail exchanger*}" ] &&
            mxnames+=(${line##* });           # Add to mxnames array
    done;
    printf 'set type=A\n' 1>&7;               # Set -type=A
    for mxname in ${mxnames[@]%.};
    do
        echo $mxname 1>&7;                    # Next query
        read -u 6 line;                       # Wait for answer and
        read -u 6 line;                       # drops two first lines
        while read -t .002 -u 6 line; do
            [ "$line" ] && [ -z "${line%%Address:*}" ] &&
                mxips+=(${line##* });         # Add to mxips array
        done;
    done;
    echo exit 1>&7;                           # End nslookup sub process
    exec 6>&-;                                # Close FD 6, then 7
    exec 7>&-;
    declare -p mxips                          # Dump result
}
```

Then

```
mxIps cathay.com.sg
declare -a mxips=([0]="104.47.125.36" [1]="104.47.126.36")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
#!/bin/bash
#nslookup but display only IP
nslookup -type=mx cathay.com.sg |
awk -F":" 'NF==2 {print $2}'
```

note that

- pipe `|` is at end of line, and use as continuation character.
- `NF==2` means we select line with 2 fields
- `print $2` will print also leading space